# How to run Containerfile inside node-template?

Tags: substrate-node-template, docker

There is Containerfile inside [substrate-node-template](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/blob/main/Containerfile). What command should I use to run this file. Is the file is similar like DockerFile?

I try to run using `docker build -f Containerfile -t node-template:latest .` command but I got this error.

```
ganesholi@Ganeshs-MacBook-Air substrate-node-template % docker build -f Containerfile -t node-template:latest .
[+] Building 3.9s (8/9)                                                                                                                     docker:desktop-linux
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                             0.0s
 => [internal] load build definition from Containerfile                                                                                                     0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 947B                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ubuntu:22.04                                                                                             3.4s
 => [auth] library/ubuntu:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                                                               0.0s
 => CACHED [1/4] FROM docker.io/library/ubuntu:22.04@sha256:ec050c32e4a6085b423d36ecd025c0d3ff00c38ab93a3d71a460ff1c44fa6d77                                0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                             0.0s
 => CANCELED [2/4] RUN apt-get update &&  DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends   ca-certificates &&  apt-get autoremo  0.4s
 => ERROR [3/4] COPY --chown=polkadot:polkadot --chmod=774 node-template /usr/bin/node-template                                                             0.0s
------                                                                                                                                                           
 > [3/4] COPY --chown=polkadot:polkadot --chmod=774 node-template /usr/bin/node-template:
------
Containerfile:23
--------------------
  21 |     
  22 |     # copy the compiled binary to the container
  23 | >>> COPY --chown=polkadot:polkadot --chmod=774 node-template /usr/bin/node-template
  24 |     
  25 |     # check if executable works in this container
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to calculate checksum of ref 57260b33-13ab-451b-9dbb-8cd096257614::rk2qq1n6p0a2l360xp3hgkrc0: "/node-template": not found
ganesholi@Ganeshs-MacBook-Air substrate-node-template %
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# copy the compiled binary to the container
COPY --chown=polkadot:polkadot --chmod=774 node-template /usr/bin/node-template
```

In fact, this line tries to copy `./node-template` to the container. Since you are in the root dir, you should change your directory first.

```
cd ./target/release
docker build -f ../../Containerfile -t node-template:latest .
```

Answer (score 0):

yes is similar to a Dockerfile and you can build/run as expected.

```bash
docker build -f Containerfile -t node-template:latest .
docker run --rm -it node-template:latest
```

*Note*: Notice that the Containerfile copy the binary from the current path.

Comment: I try to run first command but got error I have edited my question, can you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You need to have the `node-template` binary in the current directory, and also if you are in a mac the image use `ubuntu` so will not work. You can build the binary in docker to have a compatible version.